# how do I add employee ID and create collection and list for employees?

Tags: c#

```
public class Employee : IEmployee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public PayFrequency PayFrequency { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    public SickPay SickPay { get; set; }


    //create collection and list for employees
    //create employee
    //view employee
    //update employee
    //delete employee
    //add employee ID

    public static IEmployee CreateEmployee(string fName, string lName, DateTime startDate, PayFrequency payFrequency, decimal salary, SickPay sickPay)
    {
        
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.FirstName = fName;
        employee.LastName = lName;
        employee.StartDate = startDate;
        employee.PayFrequency = payFrequency;
        employee.Salary = salary;
        employee.SickPay = sickPay;
        return employee;           
    }
}
```

I have this code and I need to add an employee `ID` and create a collection and list for employees to show on console, but I am not sure how to do it.

```
void IEmployee.AddDeduction(Deduction type)
{
    //switch case or if else, 
    //based on the deduction type calculate the deduction
}

decimal IEmployee.CalculateLabourCost(DateTime weekStart, int hours, int minutes, decimal sickdays)
{
    //Calculate salary logic
    return 0;
}
```

This is also part of it. I need to calculate their salary, but I am not sure how do I do it either. I am not sure how to start the calculation. I want to calculate the employees salary according to their pay frequency and any deductions or any schemes.

Comment: Don't post pictures of code. Post code as text, formatted as code.

Comment: thanks, I did it, but I can't delete the picture now

Answer (score 1):

In your code, In properties add EmployeeId as string datatype
like

```
public string EmployeeId {get;set;}.
```

In `CreateEmployee()` method update your code as

```
Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();

EmployeeId=guid.ToString();
```

here, everytime new employee is created guid generate a unique id and stores in EmployeeId
Guid generates a unique id everytime is called.